# Как настроить запуск gitlab-runner по событию появления нового тега?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Запускать автоматическое обновление файла CHANGELOG.md (есть python скрипт) при пуше в Gitlab нового тега (0.0.1_prerelease).

Как настроить запуск gitlab-runner по событию появления нового тега?

Примерный gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
    - cl_update

cl_update:
    stage: cl_update
    before_script:
        - cd $PATH_TO_APP
        - git pull
        - echo "--- Start autochlog script ---"
    script:
        - python3 script.py
    after_script:
        - git push origin master
    tags:
        - runner
    only:
        - /^*$.prerelease/
        - master
```

Comment: попробуйте в блок `only` добавить `- tags`

Answer (score 1):

В старых версиях gitlab можно воспользоваться свойством `only: [tags]`, и он уже скоро отомрет, на замену ему приходит `rules` свойство.

Пример c `only` (deprecated soon):

```
job:
  script:
    - echo "the job is triggered from tag"
  only:
    - tags
```

Пример с `rules`:

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

Полный пример с `rules`:

```
stages:
  - cl_update

cl_update:
  stage: cl_update
  before_script:
    - cd $PATH_TO_APP
    - git pull
    - echo "--- Start autochlog script ---"
  script:
    - python3 script.py
  after_script:
    - git push origin master
  tags:
    - runner
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```